# NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My gradle sync always fails with this message on the stable android studio 3.5

This has been happening since the preview releases of versions of 3.5

> NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

The same project works on a parallel android studio. Sometimes I need to work on two instances in parallel, but I'm blocked on this error which mysteriously disappears if I quit Android Studio and restart the project. This happens on lucky days and on other days I am unable to start the project with the same error showing up repeatedly. What I mean by quit is simply exiting Android Studio and restarting it and opening my project using `Import project (Gradle, Eclipse, etc.)` instead of `Open existing Android Studio project`.

**Edit 1:** Unlike the duplicate [NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609738/ndk-resolution-outcome-project-settings-gradle-model-version-5-4-1-ndk-versio), the accepted answer is not the solution or cause to my problem. Accepted answer is an easy way to work around it, but is only a temporary fix.

**Edit 2:** 
According to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140403764#comment14,
this issue will be fixed in android 3.6 beta 1

Comment: The official Android Studio release is 3.4.2 as of today, does this stable version also have the same issue?

Comment: I need to use Android Studio 3.5 only as I am using some features that only 3.5 supports.

Comment: This issue is resolved in latest release

Comment: Have you installed NDK(Side by side)?

Comment: This issue is still coming up in android studio 3.5

Comment: Did you find a solution @Nishita ? It's happening to me after I've installed Android Studio 3.5 on my computer, after reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: @xarlymg89, Not yet. You can track this issue here, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140403764

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build.gardle(Project) and then change the classpath of gardle to 3.5.0   after Sync project android studio will use gradle-5.4.1

```
dependencies {        
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

check your version code in build.gradle app module. check whether you have a point in the version code i.e for example if you have 5.0 then change it to just 5 instead.

Comment: I get the following error: ```Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/Users/nishita.dutta/.gradle/caches/5.4.1/embedded-kotlin-repo-1.3.21-3/repo/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5/gradle-3.5.jar

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will work for everyone or not and I can't find root cause why this happening So If anyone find root cause it then please share. :D

But in my case I had **migrate project to AndroidX** and it works.

Comment: That must've been a coincidence, my project was migrated to androidX way before this issue started to come up.

Comment: yes agreed that why I told that It will not work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Open project using Import project (Gradle, Eclipse, etc.) instead of Open existing Android Studio project :)

Comment: Works at times, doesn't work other times.

Comment: @Nishita kindly check your ndk path and sync project. i

Comment: My project does not require/use an ndk.