# NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, synchronization

After updating Android Studio and Gradle to 3.5,
I now get this error:

> NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

I changed the Gradle version in build-gradle back to 3.4.2 but it didn't help.

Comment: What version *is* your NDK? How was it installed? How are you using it in your project (specified in build.gradle, local.properties, or `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`)? What's in the source.properties file in the NDK?

Comment: Thank you for your attention
my problem is solved .... just i migrated to AndroidX

Comment: I have same problem after upgrade. But my project using AndroidX andRefactor mograte dosen't work & help. Second problem. My app normally fit in singe DEX. Release is 27500 methods. After upgrade Android Studio and Kotlin + google services. App need 73000 methods ;/

Comment: Where did you get this "error"? I get this message after Android Studio update in all of my projects in the Event Log but it has no impact. Everything builds and runs as it should. I never used NDK - so I don't care if it would not work.

Comment: i think ... the "NDK version" is not main problem.... i import project again... and the problem resolved

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389443/downvoting-a-low-quality-question-results-in-incorrect-review)

Comment: It's possible none of the solutions work for you (they did not work for me). The issue is being tracked by google, you can star it there https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140403764

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I had similar problem and solved it by opening project using `Import project (Gradle, Eclipse, etc.)` instead of `Open existing Android Studio project`.

Comment: That did not solve it for me. I still have the error even with gradle 5.6.1 / plugin 3.5.0 / Android Studio 3.5.0 after importing the project again

Comment: For completeness (since I said it did not work for me) this actually *does* work for me - and is required even - to fix a separate silly sort of gradle + react-native native module compile issue. So as a "Android Studio / gradle" trick to have in your bag of tricks, it's a good one.

Comment: go to File>Project Structure>DownloadNDK which will download and add path to your local properties which might fix things up if this answer didn't work

Comment: That did not work for me, instead I had to download ndk, despite not using it.

Comment: This is not worked for me. Either below any answer not worked for me. Please help

Comment: I closed project, deleted all Build folders, .iml files, .idea folder. Then opened project and it built successfully

Comment: @DmitriyPavlukhin Thanks a lot! your comment worked! in my case, it happened after I merged two repositories.

Comment: @KingKongCoder I found that link at File > Project Structure > SDK Location > Download Android NDK

Answer (score 18):

You can download NDK from File>Project Structur>Choosing SDK location from left panel and pressing Download from NDK location part.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense if you don't use it.

Comment: The question is about the error message and an answer shouldn't require installing it to get rid of the message. The NDK is an optional package

Comment: The answer is for anyone who uses NDK and faces this error and in the question is not mentioned that he uses NDK or not .@The

Comment: NDK takes almost 1GB of your previous hard drive! And I'm not sure if there is some other impact (like memory, performance, CPU, etc.). Why do we need to download it if it is never used ? Can we just ignore the error ?

Comment: @Pablo Yes , if you don't use NDK and non of answers helped , ignore the error .

Answer (score 12):

I was having the same issue after upgrading my android studio. You just need to open `local.properties` & change `ndk.dir` path to your NDK path.

Code:

```
ndk.dir=D\:\\Android\\SDK\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\SDK
```

Comment: i coding with JAVA and i haven't NDK at all

Comment: This makes no sense if you do not have and do not want the NDK. It is an optional component

Comment: local.properties says "This file is automatically generated by Android Studio. Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!"

Answer (score 7):

I don't use NDK in my project, but I had the same problem. The problem disappeared after I updated the SDK version to the newest
***compileSdkVersion 29***

Comment: Interesting - I thought that had potential so I tried it, it still did not solve it for me.  There is an open issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140403764

Comment: @MikeHardy currently I'm using Gradle plugin version 3.5.0 and gradle version 5.4.1.
Try to change this versions, while bug will be fix. Hope it's help you.

Comment: everything is up-to-date but it still the same!

Answer (score 6):

I had a previous answer (since deleted by moderators) where I detailed that there are workarounds (as listed here) that work for some but that there is an underlying bug in gradle because the workarounds don't work for everyone (specifically: none of them work for me)

The related google issue is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140403764

Update: As of today (20190920) they indicate that they have fixed the underlying issue, so I would expect a future release of gradle after today (20190920) will contain the fix.

Update2: Today (20190926) I received a response from a googler that the problematic code was in Android Studio and it is contained on the 3.6-release branch but is not available on any publicly available build at the moment (Android Studio 3.6 Canary 12 was released just before this fix was made). That lets you know which component to update and which versions to pay attention to, anyway. Looks like Android Studio 3.6 Canary 13 and later should have it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140403764#comment13

Until then you can try the workarounds but when there's a vendor bug and workarounds don't work you just have to wait for a vendor patch.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install NDK using the SDK manager
[image: Here are the official instructions on how to install the NDK https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk]

Answer (score 4):

I first got this issue after upgrading from Android Studio 3.5.0 to 3.5.1 today.

I simply did a rebuild from the top menu Build --> Rebuild Project.

This might not work for everyone depending on what caused the issue but it worked for mine. Give it a shot.

(Also, I do not use the NDK and never have downloaded it before. Still don't have it downloaded)

Comment: I am using AS 3.5.1, my project need NDK.  Got the exact error, clean and rebuild fixed it.  Easier enough to try it first before doing anything else.

Comment: @Sean Nice, glad it worked! By the way, I think the rebuild also starts out with a clean. I realized that once when I had the lower build toolbar open and it had 'clean' as the first task. Ever since then I just started hitting the rebuild only. (Hopefully it's doing what I think it is lol).

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using NDK, ignore the error.

I have installed NDK to see if this makes any difference. There is no difference (except for an unused NDK folder of more than 2 GB :). So I removed it (i.e. delete the ndk folder and remove NDK environnent variable you have set previously).

Answer (score 3):

After my recent Android Studio upgrade I had the same error message. I tried the other answers here and none worked.  But @Zahra's answer pointed me to something that did work:

Go to **File->Project Structure...**
Under "**Android NDK Location**", click the dropdown and select the "**DEFAULT NDK Recommended**" option.

There was a slightly different path in there before I selected the default.  Somewhere upgrading using the SDK manager, the path seems to have changed.

And now in the local.properties file **sdk.dir** is set to the same directory as the "**DEFAULT NDK Recommended**" option.

Comment: After trying at least 5 different 'solutions' this one finally got me back on track, now to move on to whatever the next Android Studio bug happens to be...

Answer (score 2):

i fix it by going to `file > Invalidate Caches\Restart`
the IDE will restart and the problem will fix

Comment: go to 'file > project structre > SDK location ' and download the last NDK and go to project 'local.properties' and specific the NDK location like this 'ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Ndk'

Comment: It is doesn't make any sense if you don't use it (NDK)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. My environment is:

- Android Studio 3.5.1
- Gradle 4.4
- Android-Gradle-Plugin 3.1.2
- CMake 3.10 and 3.6

I uninstalled CMake 3.10 by SDKManager. (installed CMake is 3.6 only)

Gradle sync and build succeeded.

(1)

android-gradle-plugin 3.1.2 used CMake 3.10.

In android-gradle-plugin 3.1.2 (or 3.1.+), feature of support for CMake 3.7 and higher is a preview feature.

(from output message of `gradle assembleDebug` or `gradle sync`.)

(2)

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#use_a_custom_cmake_version

> The SDK Manager includes the 3.6.0 forked version of CMake and version 3.10.2. Projects that don't set a specific CMake version in build.gradle are built with CMake 3.6.0.

Perhaps this behavior is android-gradle-plugin 3.3 or higher.
(it is from android-studio 3.3 that can be downloaded CMake 3.10)

android-gradle-plugin 3.1.2 used latest version from installed CMake.

Comment: i missed that you wrote "Gradle 3.5" and "build-gradle back to 3.4.2".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on a mac as well.

Suggestion: Force the .gradle folder to rebuild itself..

This still shows the 'NDK Version is UNKNOWN' in the Event Log yet it builds successfully and doesn't give me any issues. (I don't have NDK downloaded)

1. Open your /Users/macuser/ folder
2. Press CMD + SHIFT + . (dot/period) to view hidden folders
3. DELETE .gradle folder
4. Restart Android Studio

This will cause Android Studio to rebuild and re-download your .gradle folder fixing your conflicting files in the process.

Comment: This worked for me but only on the first time.  If I reopened the project without first deleting .gradle then I would get the same error as before.

Comment: Yes, it seems the error will stay in the log. Mine has it as well on-going but project builds and runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved when I updated the Android Gradle Plugin Version from 3.1.4 to  3.4.0 and the Gradle Version from 4.4 to 5.1.1 at the same time. Of course, I downloaded the newest NDK(Side by Side) with SDK manager.

Comment: I also had to upgrade my Gradle version

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Android Studio was installed on a new mac. Just needed to download Android 9 (my target/compile SDK was 28) and build tools. The problem was solved after this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i fix it by upgrade to SdkVersion 29 and migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: upgrading target and compile version to sdk 29 worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading I've got the very same problem in one of my projects.
I solved it just deleting the line ndk.dir=D:\Android\SDK\ndk-bundle from the local.properties file.

Comment: The answer might be made more valuable by stating how you knew where to find the file in android studio or on the file system and your reasoning in determining that was the change to make.

Comment: ndk.dir is not set in my projects. I never used NDK. Nevertheless I get this "error" in Android Studio 3.5.

Comment: Same as The Incredible Jan, this was not in my local.properties yet I still get this message. So it is not a complete solution but perhaps it could help some

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after adding a couple of libraries in the app-level `build.gradle` file.
The solution was just to **clean the project**.
In the menu bar choose: `Build >> Clean Project`
After that, the error was gone for me. I didn't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error (and several others) after importing a project from version control via Bitbucket hyperlink.

Once imported, close the project and re-import it using `File > New > Import Project`. After that  everything built correctly.
(The NDK path was already specified properly, and only importing as new worked)

Meta:
`Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 8, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
Gradle 3.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved for me after checking Suggestions in Project structure and updated the two suggested updates. Sorry I can't remember the module names as they disappeared as soon as I pressed update for each of them and graddle sync. started automatically and after this problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating Android Studio.
My problem is solved by after updating Android SDK Build-Tools.
[Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools->Android SDK Build-Tools].

Then try to Clean the project
[Build->Clean Project].

Finally restart the Android Studio IDE......

Answer (score 0):

downgrading ndk version from 20 to r17c and cmake version from 3.10 to 3.6.411459 solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I just closed project, closed android studio, restarted my PC, tracked my project and deleted the .Idea folder in "B:/PROJECTNAME/.idea" and voila.

Problem solved. It resyncs. N/B: my gradle is androidx. goodluck to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Change the claaspath to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2' in build.gradle script

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I recently downloaded the latest version of Android studio and got similar error. So eventually I created a new project. 
Selected Kotlin Language then Jelly Bean (talking 'bout the options to pick from).
Then the whole synching began but the 1st sync failed and eventually it auto-synced again and everything began to work. 
Did modify the default codes (text) since I'm a beginner but got no error messages.
The preview was OK and I continued my learning.
Sorry I couldn't explain it better. I'm just a beginner.
Oh! You need to be connected to the Internet for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem occurred after an Android Studio upgrade and you initiated a plugin update from right bottom notification: Open `File > Project structure`, then change the Android Gradle version to your Android Studio version and downgrade the Gradle version to the previous one.

In my case, I downgraded the Android Gradle plugin from 3.5.3 to 3.2.1 and the Gradle version from 5.4.1 to 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the gradle version of the gradle-wrapper.properties file from 4.1 to 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and none of the solutions worked for me. Problem is, this error or warning might appear for very broad reasons. You can follow these steps to find out what is wrong:

**NDK is missing**

When Gradle starts to compile native dependencies it creates ".cxx" folder in your "app" folder. inside that folder you can find "ndk_locator_record.json" file, which is very strange type of log file. It is basically all the paths Gradle checks to find NDK folder. If there is any error or mismatch on NDK version numbers you can see in this file.

**NDK build fails**

for some unknown reasons (maybe bug in Gradle) ndk build does not show actual error on event log window, instead it shows a failure, like *Gradle sync failed: executing external native build for ndkBuild ....* following by *NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN*.

In this case go back to .cxx > ndkBuild > debug > x86(x64 or any other cpu arch) 
Here in this folder you can find "json_generation_record.json" file, it is same type of log, usually last entry has the actual error. For example, for me was

```
 ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
 make: *** No rule to make target '../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'.  Stop.
```

From here you have a starting point to find out what is going wrong under hood.

Answer (score 0):

If the NDK is not install, and the Android Project requires it then first install the NDK.

On **windows OS** add the NDK path to **PAT**H environment variable. This will fix the version issue.

In my case the NDK path is
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before and I fixed it by making sure to have the right permissions to the app directory.

I am using macOS, so I did:

```sh
chmod -R 777 your_android_project
```

and the issue was gone.

Answer (score -1):

i have this problem too when I updated the Android Gradle Plugin Version from 3.1.2 to 3.5.1

Here is how to solve this issue :

Go to `gradle.properties file` in root folder of your project and add **`android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`**

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem and instead of opening project i import it from

> **`File -> New -> Import Project...`**

and problem solved