# Android Studio 3.5 update creates this warning in event log

Tags: android, android-studio

This wasn't there before this update, does anyone know what is causing this

```
NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Related  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609738/ndk-resolution-outcome-project-settings-gradle-model-version-5-4-1-ndk-versio

Comment: I have seen it, my project is primarily in AndroidX so it does not solve anything

Comment: To few information. Try to elaborete. Also check if your dependencies in the gradle are all up to date.