# Manifest merger failed issue android support

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am getting this error after inserting a dependent implementation in my project.

> NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1,
>   NDK version is UNKNOWN
>
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-95:19 to override.

The included dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
```

my build.gradle looks like this:

[image]

If I remove the dependency import, the error disappears. I need the dependency in question to read qr code.

I read the post below but none of the solutions worked for me.

[NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609738/ndk-resolution-outcome-project-settings-gradle-model-version-5-4-1-ndk-versio)

Comment: The message about the NDK isn't an error. This isn't related to the NDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest you downgrade the version of the `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision'` from `18.0.0` to a lower version.

Try using `17.0.2` or `16.2.0`. You can check for other versions in [Google's Maven Repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) under **com.google.android.gms** -> **play-services-vision**