# Best sample app for Oculus development with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, oculus, openxr

Can anybody recommend a working Android Studio sample app that I can use for Oculus Quest 2, preferably with good documentation?  I am looking for something I can build and run to start playing with their [OpenXR Mobile SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-openxr-mobile-sdk/).

I am on an Intel Macbook Pro running macOS Big Sur, and I tried with the latest stable Android Studio release (Arctic Fox).

I have tried two different samples so far:

1. `VrSamples/VrCubeworld_Framework` - from the official Oculus docs:

- [Android Development Software Setup](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/native/android/mobile-studio-setup-android/)
- [Getting Started with Oculus Native Samples: Import Gradle Project](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/native/android/mobile-studio-basics/#getting-started-with-oculus-native-samples-import-gradle-project)

After following all the steps, I keep hitting this error:

> ```
> NDK not configured. Download it with SDK manager. Preferred NDK version is '21.0.6113669'.
> ```

I'm convinced my NDK is installed:

[image: ndk_installed]

[image: ndk_setings]

I believe I've tried every workaround listed in the [popular Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609738/ndk-resolution-outcome-project-settings-gradle-model-version-5-4-1-ndk-versio?page=2&tab=active#tab-top), and the linked Google issue.

2. `hello_xr` - a [comment](https://forums.oculusvr.com/t5/OpenXR-Development/How-To-Build-Hello-Xr-sample-with-Android-Version/m-p/860188/highlight/true#M85) on the Oculus Forum links to [this helpful blog post](https://gayanediriweera.github.io/code/2021/04/06/how-to-run-helloxr-on-oculus-quest.html) with more detailed instructions than the [official Oculus docs](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/native/android/mobile-openxr/#getting-started-with-the-openxr-mobile-sdk).  Unfortunately, after following those, I hit this build error:

> ```
> C/C++: /Users/dj/Code/OpenXR-SDK-Source/src/CMakeLists.txt debug|armeabi-v7a : CMake Error at /Users/dj/Code/OpenXR-SDK-Source/src/version.cmake:25 (file):   
>   file STRINGS file  
>   "/Users/dj/Code/OpenXR-SDK-Source/src/include/openxr/openxr.h" cannot be read. 
> Call Stack (most recent call first):   
>   CMakeLists.txt:318 (include)
> ```

There doesn't appear to be an `include` folder under [`src`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenXR-SDK-Source/tree/master/src), and there is no `openxr.h` in the top level [`include/openxr`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenXR-SDK-Source/tree/master/include/openxr) folder.

**UPDATE**: At Jherico's suggestion, I downloaded [Oculus OpenXR Mobile SDK v1.0.13](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-openxr-mobile-sdk/1.0.13) and [OpenXR-SDK-Source release-1.0.13](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenXR-SDK-Source/releases/tag/release-1.0.14), and followed the instructions again to exactly match the versions used in the blog post, and ultimately I did get it working!

I created https://github.com/daj/OculusHelloXR to snapshot my working Android Studio project with all its dependencies, with individual commits for each step that I followed (I had to make a couple of changes to steps in the blog post to get it working).

I wrote everything up in this blog post: https://daj.medium.com/oculus-vr-for-android-developers-a38134c759b0

Answer (score 1):

The blog post instructions are likely out of date, since they're from April and the most recent version of the OpenXR SDK has it's own new `build.gradle` file for hello_xr that was added in 1.0.20 in October.

If you want to go by the blog post, I'd suggest that after you check out the OpenXR-SDK-Source repository, you then run `git checkout release-1.0.14` since that would be the version that the blog post was written against.

Alternatively, you can just ignore the blog post and try importing the [build.gradle](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenXR-SDK-Source/blob/master/src/tests/hello_xr/build.gradle) project directly into Android Studio (basically following the "Import Gradle Project" steps you linked to, but importing `hello_xr` from the *current version* of the OpenXR-SDK-Source project instead) and try seeing it that builds.

If you're still getting NDK errors you might try explicitly setting the `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` environment variable, and make sure it's visible to your build process.

Comment: Good idea to try the exact releases that they used in the blog post.  When I used v1.0.13 of the Oculus OpenXR Mobile SDK *and* OpenXR-SDK-Source release-1.0.13, then eventually I got it working.  Thanks for the idea!  BTW, I did have `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` set up, but that didn't seem to help (though maybe I have a mistake in making it visible to my build process).

Comment: In case it helps others, I have now collected together all the steps into a single repo, with individual commits for each step that I followed: https://github.com/daj/OculusHelloXR